# TeamCity - Artifact dependency view

Tags: teamcity

I know that I can see what dependecies a specific project has. But it is possible to see the other way round: Can I see which projects have an artifact dependency on "my project"?

I'm not talking about the view "This build is used by other builds" because I can only see a project that has used this specific build. But I would like to know every project that is using "my project"?